# QBSDK Noob Issue with SDK and samples

Tags: c#, visual-studio, quickbooks

1. I am using C# in VS 2010
2. I am using Quickbooks 2011 Premium
3. I downloaded the latest QBSDK (v12.0)
4. I open the QB sample data file (sample_product-based business.qbw)
5. I open the `InvoiceAdd` project (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK12.0\samples\qbdt\c-sharp\QBFC\QBInvoiceAdd`) - I converted their project to VS 2010 and then I set the build option to x86
6. At the line:

   ```
   sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
   ```

   I get the error

   > Can't open quickbooks: Quickbooks can't start because it is already running

I have tried entering a full path into the `beginsession` function call but I get no further.

Please help me find what I am doing wrong.  Am I using the wrong SDK for a desktop app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something? The error message is "Quickbooks can't start because it is already running". So the problem is not with the path - according to this message.

Exit Quickbooks and possibly reboot the computer.

Ok. Sorry to state the obvious! [This page](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/SLN41846) suggests that this was an error in QB 2011 that was fixed in 2012. A little digging may uncover a fix for QB 2011 Premium.

Alternatively, it might be UAC control. Temporarily reduce the level of UAC to nothing to discover if this is the cause.

**Added**: The third option is to disable **Quickbooks Instant Start** in QBs Preferences, which keeps QB running as a background process. Reboot the computer after this change.

Comment: Tried that... thanks... but nothing doing.   I think the problem may be due to something in permissions.  But there seems to be no way to add my app to QB permissible apps.

Comment: OK... tried the 2nd option... cannot seem to find a solution for 2011 short of upgrading to 2012.  :-(

Comment: Tried the third option.  Setting UAC to nothing proved fruitless.  Damn... I liked that one!

Comment: trying the instant start now.

Comment: Don't forget to reboot, otherwise you will need to go into the Services and stop all currently running QB items.

Comment: OK... stoopid question... where is Quickbooks Instant Start in the preferences?  Cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Apparently: "From the Edit menu, select Preferences.
Select General icon and on the My Preferences tab. Clear the Keep QuickBooks running for quick startups checkbox and click Ok."

Comment: OK... did that... and the error has changed to a fascinating one: the application trying to connect to quickbooks does not support quickbooks premier.  Am I using the right API?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to help further. Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083744/what-is-the-best-way-to-integrate-with-quickbooks-from-c-sharp-code) is worth reading. Good luck. Perhaps someone else will contribute.

Comment: Turns out, Andrew, that I think you solved the problem.  The last error I received was due to a small piece of code I added to fix this early on that forced the authorization.  But it did not allow premier.  Once I removed the line of code it worked.